# Accessing solutions of coupled differential equations solved using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, parametric-functions

I have the following linear coupled differential equations (`y , z`) that I wish to solve with a varying parameter `a`

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a*y[t] + z[t], z'[t] == y[t] + a^2*z[t], y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

I wish to access, say, the value of `y` at time `t=5` and `a=4`. I do `y[4][5]/.sol` and it does not return anything. Usually, when solving for one variable, the first argument of  `y` should take on the value of the parameter `a`. How should I go about accessing the values of `y` and `z` in this case?

**Edit:** I tried clearing Global, as suggested but the problem persists

[image]

**Edit 2:** I simply did not do `y[4][5]/.sol`. This was my fault. However, I see the following warning. Should I be worried about this ?

[image]

Comment: Start with `Clear["Global\`*"]` to remove any old definitions. Then after your code, `y[4][5] /. sol` returns `5.70136*10^32`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for the response. I've got it to work, but it is giving a warning. I am not sure if I should be concerned with it?

Comment: When running the code with `13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)`, for `{y[4][5], z[4][5]} /. sol` I get `{5.70136*10^32, 6.88882*10^33}` without any warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a*y[t] + z[t], 
    z'[t] == y[t] + a^2*z[t], y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0}, {y, z}, 
    {t, 0, 10}, {a}];

{y[4][5], z[4][5]} /. sol

(* {5.70136*10^32, 6.88882*10^33} *)

Manipulate[
 LogLogPlot[Evaluate[{y[a][t], z[a][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    {HoldForm@y["a"][t], HoldForm@z["a"][t]},
    {0.4, 0.5}]],
 {{a, 4}, 0, 8, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I will recheck my Mathematica version. I think this is what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution somewhat more convenient, especially if the solutions have to be used in more than one place:

```
{ysol, zsol} = {y, z} /. ParametricNDSolve[
   {
     y'[t] == a*y[t] + z[t], 
     z'[t] == y[t] + a^2*z[t],
     y[0] == 1, z[0] == 0
   }, 
   {y, z}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}
]
```

`ysol` and `zsol` can then be used e.g. like this:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{ysol[a][t], zsol[a][t]}, {t, 0, 10}], 
  {a, 0.5, 1.5}
]
```